# JAX-RS method has no Path or HTTP method annotations

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I am implementation another implementation for existing interface using Spring and Apache CXF. When tomcat is starting up, it show below error message :

> Method getSomething in ModuleInterface has no JAX-RS Path or HTTP
>   Method annotations

And, both endpoints are returning 404.

I am not sure what am I missing. Any idea anyone?

```
public interface ModuleInterface {
   public Response getSomething(@Valid RequestObj obj);
}
```

--

```
@Service
@Path("/foo")
public class FooClass implements moduleInterface {
public Response getSomething(@Valid Request obj){
// code
}
}
```

--

```
@Service
@Path("/new/foo")
public class FooV2Class implements moduleInterface {
public Response getSomething(@Valid Request obj){
// code
}
}
```

--

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:/META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml", "classpath:/META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"})
public class APIConfig {
@Autowired @Lazy ModuleInterface moduleInterface;

@Bean
public Server initCxfServer(){
    JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    sf.setServiceBeanObjects(getJaxRsResources());
    sf.setProviders(Arrays.asList(
            new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider()
    ));

    return sf.create();
}

private Object[] getJaxRsResources() {
    return new Object[]{
        moduleInterface
    };
}

private HashMap getExtMaps() {
    return new HashMap<String,String>(){{
        put("json","application/json;charset=utf-8");
        put("xml","application/xml;charset=utf-8");
        put("wadl","application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml");
        put("desc","application/vnd.sun.desc+json;charset=utf-8");
       }};
}
```

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16956510/3143670)

Comment: I tried the suggested approach but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding name of the bean and using qualifier annotation

```
@Service("foo")
@Path("/foo")
public class FooClass implements ModuleInterface {
public Response getSomething(@Valid Request obj){
// code
}
}
--

@Service("foov2")
@Path("/new/foo")
public class FooV2Class implements moduleInterface {
public Response getSomething(@Valid Request obj){
// code
}
}

@Component
public class Service {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("foo")
ModuleInterface moduleInterface
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This may happend if you annonate the arguments in boths methods, in the interface and in the implementantion class, with `@Valid` (or even other annotation like `@Context`).

Keep the annotation only on the arguments of the method that you annotated with the `@Path` (either in the interface, either in the implementation class) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let CXF know about your services and/or configure CXF.

See: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-ConfiguringJAX-RSservicesincontainerwithSpringconfigurationfile for CXF JAX-RS configuration with Spring.

**EDIT**

If you have multiple instances, which one do you expect to be loaded with following line ?

```
@Autowired @Lazy ModuleInterface moduleInterface;
```

Shouldn't an array achieve what you want ? Like :

```
@Autowired @Lazy ModuleInterface[] moduleInterfaces;
```

Comment: I have edited the question and add configuration as well

Answer (score 0):

Your classes are scanned for methods which can receive requests (`Resource methods`).
`getSomething` is a candidate since it has the parameter annotation `@Valid` but it does not qualify as resource method since it is missing a JAX-RS Path or HTTP Method annotation.

For instance adding a `@GET` annotation will do it (if you want to receive HTTP GET requests via this method).

```
public interface ModuleInterface {
    @GET
    public Response getSomething(@Valid RequestObj obj);
}
```

Comment: If I have only have one implementation that it works fine even without specifying GET annotation. I understand that I need to specify if there will be multiple implementation but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same warning. In my case I used CXF 3.1.3 and I missed to add the spring feature within karaf.

For more details see [Migration Guide](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/31-migration-guide.html) to CXF 3.1.x