# Reading a list of json files produces "no resource classes found" error

Tags: java, json

I have a list of json files

```
List<file> mylistJson;

for (file myjsonfile : mylistJson)
{
    Bufferedreader br = new bufferedreader(new FileReader(myjsonfile)); 
    String st; 
    While((st = br.readline()) != null) 
     System.out.println(st); 

 }
```

Error message:

> [error] no resource classes found, skipping

Comment: The line starting with `Bufferedreader br` is cut off in the middle.

Comment: The first file to read only has the following characters in the file [  ] while the others have more data. I see the file within the list of files, when the file reader process starts, the FileReader throws an error, failed to excute, system can not find the specified file.

Comment: @Barmar scroll over if you are using a mobile device

Comment: It looks like this one the code  bufferedreader

Comment: I'm on a desktop, I don't see any scroll bars.

Comment: All I see is `Bufferedreader br = new bufferedreader(new`.

Comment: Bufferedreader br = new bufferedreader(new FileReader(myjsonfile));

Comment: You should edit the question, not just post a comment. I've done it for you.

Comment: Oh, now I see, they were split over multiple lines.

Comment: You should post the full stackstrace. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244112/no-resource-classes-found-on-a-cxf-servlet for an example of another question about this error

Comment: Again, put it in the question, not comments, so you can format it readably.

Comment: Do you have a way for me to send you the stack trace? I tried but it says i need a reputation of 10

Comment: I don't know Java, sending it to me will not be at all helpful. You should be able to paste it into the question, mark it, then type Control-k to mark is pre-formatted code.

Comment: I was able to get to work. I change it to myjsonfile.getabsolutepath.